# understanding the uniqueness of a mobius transformation.

Tags: mobius-transformation

When given the mobius transformation and three points $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for $z,a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C},ad-bc\neq0, f(z_1)=f1,f(z_2)=f_2,f(z_3)=f_3$,

what is the approach to determine the unique transformation? Because during the substitutions I always end up with a quadratic equation involving one of the variables. How do I then definitively disprove the other solution?

Comment: Is it possible that this leads to a sign ambiguity for $a$ (say), but that the same sign ambiguity occurs in $b,c,d$, so that it cancels itself out of the fraction $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$? (Remember that a single Möbius transformation is represented by infinitely many quadruples $a,b,c,d$, since one can scale by a nonzero constant.)

Comment: yes, theres is a sign ambiguity, but what do you mean it cancels? what happens is when i find the two $a$(say), i then obtain 2 set of $b,c,d$ accordingly. However, when substituting the second set back into $ad-bc = C$ where C is a constant given by the question, it produces not C, and when the transformation is plotted, the second set doesn't map all three points, but I don't understand why it shouldn't equals to C.

Comment: "...What is the approach to determine the unique transformation? ...How do I then definitively disprove the other solution?".  The direction of the implication, when resolving the corresponding generated quadratic equation is **this direction**: $\implies.~~$  This means that the roots of the quadratic equation are **candidate solutions**, that **each** may or may not satisfy the original constraints.  Therefore, you must **automatically** check each individual candidate solution against the original constraints, to see if the candidate solution is *successful*.

Comment: It's not clear we're going to be able to provide further assistance without details of computations in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea is to use $(0,\infty,1)$ as a "way station" (midpoint) between two triples.

To go from $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ to $(0,\infty,1)$, we may put $z-z_1$ in a numerator to ensure $f(z_1)=0$, we may put $z-z_2$ in a denominator to ensure $f(z_2)=\infty$, and then normalize to ensure $f(z_3)=1$:

$$ f(z)=\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\cdot\frac{z_3-z_2}{z_3-z_1}, $$

the "cross-ratio." The corresponding matrix for this transformation is the product

$$ \begin{bmatrix} z_3-z_2 & 0 \\ 0 & z_3-z_1 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -z_1 \\ 1 & -z_2 \end{bmatrix}. $$

To go from $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ to $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$, then, we compose with the inverse of the transformation that goes from $(f_1,f_2,f_3)$ to $(0,\infty,1)$, which (using $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$) would yield

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -f_1 \\ 1 & -f_2 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
 \begin{bmatrix} f_3-f_2 & 0 \\ 0 & f_3-f_1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} z_3-z_2 & 0 \\ 0 & z_3-z_1 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -z_1 \\ 1 & -z_2 \end{bmatrix}. $$

---

The title suggests you also want to understand why there is a *unique* transformation between triples. Suppose there were two transformations between a pair of triples. We may compose both with a map that turns the second triple into $(0,\infty,1)$, so we end up with two transformations that turn a triple into $(0,\infty,1)$. But then we may *precompose* with a map that turns $(0,\infty,1)$ into the first triple, and we end up with two transformations from $(0,\infty,1)$ to itself. But it is an easier exercise to show there is only one such transformation.